# Block not found within template following upgrade of Twig and upgrade to Symfony 2.8.18

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig, symfony-2.8

I have just upgraded from Symfony 2.7 to 2.8.18 and I am now getting the following error when I access a page with a form which was previously working before the upgrade.

> Block "_appbundle_crmpicco_reserve_widget" on template
>   "::base.html.twig" does not exist.

`reserve.html.twig`:

```
// this extends the top-level ::base.html.twig
{% extends "AppBundle:CRMPicco:base.html.twig" %} 
{% block _appbundle_crmpicco_reserve_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
    {# Call the parent setup #}
    {{- parent() -}}

    {# Display the widget now #}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <span class='validation-box glyphicon'></span>
    {% endspaceless %}
{%- endblock %}
```

There was also a noticeable upgrade in Twig as part of my `composer update`:

```
  - Removing twig/twig (v1.24.2)
  - Installing twig/twig (v2.2.0)
    Downloading: 100%
```

Has template inheritance changed in more recent versions? I can't find anything in the [Symfony upgrade docs](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/UPGRADE-2.8.md).

Comment: You can try to keep Twig 1: `composer require "twig/twig:~1.24"`

Comment: @A.L Yes, I will try reverting to Twig 1. Should I not be able to do this with Twig 2 though?

Comment: Twig 2 requires php 7 afaik

Comment: 1) According to me this should be entirely possible in Twig 2, so that shouldn't be the issue. 2) You do have  a rogue `-` sign in your `endblock` statement. That shouldn't be the cause of this issue though!

Comment: Show us `AppBundle:CRMPicco:base.html.twig`

Comment: @BenHillier the `-`  sign is used to remove white spaces, see [the documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/1.x/templates.html#templates-whitespace-control).

Comment: @A.L I never knew that! I've learned something useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that the block `_appbundle_crmpicco_reserve_widget` does not exist in the parent `AppBundle:CRMPicco:base.html.twig` template. In Twig 1.x, calling `parent()` inside the child template silently returned. This was deprecated in Twig 1.29 and throws an exception since Twig 2.0.